# Simple multithreading mutex example is incorrect

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, mutex, waitformultipleobjects

I expect to get numbers from 0 to 4 in random order, but instead, I have some unsynchronized mess

What i do wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>

using namespace std;

void addQuery(void *v );

HANDLE ghMutex;

int main()
{
    HANDLE hs[5];
    ghMutex = CreateMutex( NULL, FALSE, NULL);         
    for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        hs[i] = (HANDLE)_beginthread(addQuery, 0, (void *)&i);
        if (hs[i] == NULL) 
        {
            printf("error\n"); return -1;
        }
    }

    printf("WaitForMultipleObjects return: %d error: %d\n",
         (DWORD)WaitForMultipleObjects(5, hs, TRUE, INFINITE), GetLastError());


    return 0;
}

void addQuery(void *v )
{
    int t = *((int*)v);
    WaitForSingleObject(ghMutex, INFINITE);

    cout << t << endl;

    ReleaseMutex(ghMutex);
    _endthread();
}
```

Comment: ["You are also able to use the thread handle returned by _beginthreadex with the synchronization APIs, **which you cannot do with _beginthread.**"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to read and write the shared variable *inside* the lock. You are reading it outside of the lock and thus rendering the lock irrelevant.

But even that's not enough since your shared variable is a loop variable that you are writing to without protection of the lock.  A much better example would run like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>

using namespace std;

void addQuery(void *v );

HANDLE ghMutex;
int counter = 0;

int main()
{
    HANDLE hs[5];
    ghMutex = CreateMutex( NULL, FALSE, NULL);         
    for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        hs[i] = (HANDLE)_beginthread(addQuery, 0, NULL);
        if (hs[i] == NULL) 
        {
            printf("error\n"); return -1;
        }
    }

    printf("WaitForMultipleObjects return: %d error: %d\n",
         (DWORD)WaitForMultipleObjects(5, hs, TRUE, INFINITE), GetLastError());


    return 0;
}

void addQuery(void *v)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(ghMutex, INFINITE);

    cout << counter << endl;
    counter++;

    ReleaseMutex(ghMutex);
    _endthread();
}
```

If you can, use a critical section rather than a mutex because they are simpler to use and more efficient. But they have the same semantics in that they only protect code inside the locking block.

Note: Jerry has pointer out some other problems, but I've concentrated on the high level trheading and serialization concerns.

Comment: thank you! Example with global `int counter` is clear to me. But how i can pass some data to created thread-function?

Comment: You pass it the same way you were doing, but not a pointer to a loop counter!!

Answer (score -1):

Your **`synchronization`** has some issues as you want to get numbers from 0 to 4 in random order.

The problem is that the variable `i` is write outside the lock and every time the `addQuery` method get called by the execution of a thread, it get the modified version of variable `i`. That why you may see `5` as the value at the output for all.

So, here is my fix for this scenario. Instead of pass the address of variable `i` in parameters of the function `addQuery`, you should pass it's value. Hope it helps:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>

using namespace std;

void addQuery(void *v);

HANDLE ghMutex;

int main()
{
    HANDLE hs[5];
    ghMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        hs[i] = (HANDLE)_beginthread(addQuery, 0, (void *)i);

        if (hs[i] == NULL)
        {
            printf("error\n"); return -1;
        }
    }

    printf("WaitForMultipleObjects return: %d error: %d\n",
    (DWORD)WaitForMultipleObjects(5, hs, TRUE, INFINITE), GetLastError());


    return 0;
}

void addQuery(void *v)
{
    int t = (int)v;
    WaitForSingleObject(ghMutex, INFINITE);
    cout << t << endl;

    ReleaseMutex(ghMutex);
    _endthread();
}
```